# Como resolver o erro "ReferenceError" para nodeJS no AWS Lambda acessando o DynamoDB

Tags: node.js

Ao usar o AWS Lambda para inserir registros no dynamoDB, via console, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
{
    "errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
    "stack": [
        "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
        "    at file:///var/task/index.mjs:1:13",
        "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)",
        "    at async Promise.all (index 0)",
        "    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)",
        "    at async _tryAwaitImport (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:921:16)",
        "    at async _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:970:86)",
        "    at async _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:994:16)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1"
    ]
}
```

ABAIXO O CÓDIGO QUE ESTÁ SENDO USADO.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk"); 


const insertArtist = async (event) => { 
    
  
    // const {id, name, age, startDate} = JSON.parse(event.body);
    
    const id = event.id;
    const name = event.name;
    const age = event.age;
    const startDate = event.startDate;
    
    var responseBody = "";
    var statusCode = 0;
  
    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    
    const newArtist = {
        id,
        name,
        age,
        startDate
    };
    
    try {
        await dynamodb.put({
            TableName: "Artist",
            Item: newArtist
        }).promise();
        
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(newArtist);
        statusCode = 200;

    } catch (e) {
        
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(e);
        statusCode = 400;
        
    }
    
    var response = {
        
        responseBody: responseBody,
        statusCode: statusCode
        
    };    

    return response;
    
};

module.exports = {
    handler:insertArtist
};
```

Comment: Você pode verificar a parte `type` no arquivo `package.json` e veja se a parte do `"type"` for `"module"`. Se sim, você receberá este erro. Você tem que colocar `"commonjs"` no lugar. Assim: `"type": "commonjs"`

Answer (score -2):

Você pode tentar usar essa importação
const AWS = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");

Pelo que parece a versão do SDK para essa versão do node tem outra importação.

Answer (score -2):

Parece apenas uma configuração errada com o NODEJS, já que aparentemente ele não reconhece a forma de importar com o 'require', provavelmente apenas mudar o type no package.json deve resolver:

"type":"module" para "type":"commonjs"

[Exemplo de package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk5pP.png)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).